How to handle(Send) the jwt token and user data after the login
I made an app but im beginner and i didint know that i need to add an auth method .Im trying to use jwt but i dont understand how i must send back the user data .
For start i just put the user data and send them as
 const response = {
            status: 200,
            userId: results[0].id, 
            email : results[0].email,
            username : results[0].username,
 };      
           return res.status(200).json(response);

after the login i have found 3 ways to do it but i dont know which of them is the "best way" ,more secure and more optimize:
1)The user token with userId only
const token = jwt.sign(results[0].id, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '1h'});
const response = token;
return res.status(200).json(response);

2)The user token ecrypted with some user info data
const response = {
            status: 200,
            userId: results[0].id, 
            email : results[0].email,
            username : results[0].username,
};
const token = jwt.sign(response, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '1h' });
return res.status(200).json(token);


3)The token asseperate data with user data
const token = jwt.sign(results[0].id, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '1h'});
const response = {
            status: 200,
            token : token,
            userId: results[0].id, 
            email : results[0].email,
            username : results[0].username,
};
return res.status(200).json(response);

When the user logs in i pass the data to a provider in order to use them for some of my screens-pages .
So how i handle this situation and how the user make changes his username-password if he likes ?
He send back the token to the server and the server decrypts it or it send the token with the userId(like this :
const response = {
            token: token,
            userId: results[0].id, 
            username : newUsername
 };     

) for example and the new username-password?
Thank you for your time .

2 is the common way. By verifying the signature of the jwt, this ensures the payload is not tampered .

To make a authorized request with the jwt, usually we put the jwt in the request's Authoriztion header as a Bearer token. Take a look at this article

You have to sent the token in request's Authoriztion header as follows

Thanks guys for the response , and sorry for the late answer i wanted to try it first without bothering you much , i post an answer can you check it and tell me your opinion ? i will much appreciate :) , it works when i run it but i dont know if i must make a second request with the token after the login takes place in order to send some user info data like username and email for some of my pages-screens .(its on the bottom of my answer,i make also an example in the start of how to change the user data from frontend to backend) thanks.


So how i handle this situation and how the user make changes his
username-password if he likes ?

You have almost got the answer

User logins into the server then server response with a jwt token
User must send this token in following request header (Authoriztion)
Server must validate the jwt to authorise the user is a actual user

So the jwt must signed with user.id, it's enough to identify a  user.
Let's imagine a scenario as you mentioned about user password change, so user had login into app and got the token then this happens
front-end (I'm using js)
const myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// HERE I'm sending the token
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c");

const urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("username", "\"newUserName\"");

const requestOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: "follow"
};

fetch("YOUR_API/change-name", requestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));

Back-end
app.post('/change-name', function(req,res){
    const  header = req.header('authorization');
    if(!header){
        res.status(400).json({
            error:{
                code: 400,
                message:"No auth headers found"
            }
        })
    } 
    
    const authorization = header.split(' ');
    const token = authorization.length == 2 ? authorization[1] : authorization[0];
    const { id: userId } = jwt.verify(
        token,
        process.env.APP_SECRET
    );
    if(!userId){
        res.status(401).json({
            error:{
                code: 401,
                message:"Unauthorized access"
            }
        })
    }

    // user name change logic
})

Also you can create a middleware for token validation
Use this to create token
const token = jwt.sign(
    {
      id: userId
    },
    process.env.APP_SECRET,
    {
        algorithm:"HS512",
        expiresIn: expires,
        issuer: process.env.APP_NAME,
        jwtid: crypto.randomUUID()
    }
)


ok i think i got it ,can you have a look in my code if you dont mind ?
I will post it below

Sorry for the late answer i wanted to try it first and dont bother you guys much .

sure , no prob :)

Front end (Flutter)
function random(
    ) async {
  try {
    final response =
        await http.post(Uri.parse('${dotenv.env['baseUrl']}/random_url'),
            body: jsonEncode({
              //'user': Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false).userId,
              'username': data1,
              'email': data2,
            }),
            headers: await token_Headers());
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return http.Response('Error occurred', 400);
  }
}

Headers :
Future<Map<String, String>> token_Headers() async {
//here i get the token after the login that is stored in local storage
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final token = await prefs.getString('token');
//here i make the headers
final Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
  };
  return requestHeaders;
}

Back end
//Suppose i change the username and email with the Change Class.
    async function(req, res) {

        const { username, email } = req.body;
        
       
        try{
            if(await Change_Model.function2(req.user.id,username,email)){
                res.sendStatus(200);
            }
            else{
                res.sendStatus(400);
            }
        }catch (error) {
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
    },


Token decrypt :
//Here i take the id of the user from the token
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
  if (authHeader == null) return res.sendStatus(401);

  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
  if (!token) return res.sendStatus(401); 

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, (err, user) => {
    if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
    req.user = user;
    next();
  });
}

module.exports = authenticateToken;

This is how i store the token after the login in front end with SharedPreferences for local storage:
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final token = jsonDecode(response.body)['token'].toString();
      final email = jsonDecode(response.body)['email'].toString();
      final username = jsonDecode(response.body)['username'].toString();
//Provider
      Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false)
          .setUserId(email, username);
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setString('token', token);

      Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.home);

Is it bad if i send back some info data of the user after the login takes place if i want to diplay them in some of my screens ?
It will be better if i make another request with the token first or its fine?
Thank you for your time.
